# Paperclip and AWS S3, expiring_url, undefined method `credentials' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use expiring_url in Paperclip to access objects on Amazon S3 (using Paperclip's [instructions](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3)), but am getting an error:

```
undefined method `credentials' for nil:NilClass
aws-sdk-core (2.5.3) lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb:44:in `initialize'
aws-sdk-core (2.5.3) lib/aws-sdk-core/s3/presigner.rb:98:in `new'
```

Things work spiffily if I just use @object.attachment.url, but @object.attachment.expiring_url gives the error.  Why is this happening?

development.rb:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      storage: :s3,
      url: ":s3_alias_url",
      path: "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
      s3_host_alias: "example.cloudfront.net/assets",
      s3_credentials: {
          bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
          access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
          s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
      },
      s3_permissions: :private
  }
```

model:

```
has_attached_file :attachment
```

controller:

```
def download
    redirect_to @object.attachment.expiring_url(10)
end
```

view:

```
<%= link_to "attachment", download_object_path(@object) %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure this is worth posting, or if I should delete the entire question.

The problem ended up being that I was referring to "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" in my development.rb, but I was using "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**_ID**" as my environment variable.

I can't say the error message was helpful.  I still wonder why `.url` was working when `.expiring_url` wasn't?